# Copying files from one location of a server to another using python

Tags: python, server

Say I have a file that contains the different locations where some `'.wav'` files are present on a server. For example say the content of the text file `location.txt` containing the locations of the wav files is this

```
/home/user/test_audio_folder_1/audio1.wav
/home/user/test_audio_folder_2/audio2.wav
/home/user/test_audio_folder_3/audio3.wav
/home/user/test_audio_folder_4/audio4.wav
/home/user/test_audio_folder_5/audio5.wav
```

Now what I want to do is that I want to copy these files from different locations within the server to a particular directory within that server, for example say `/home/user/final_audio_folder/` and this directory will contain all the audio files from `audio1.wav` to `audio5.wav`

I am trying to perform this task by using `shutil`, but the main problem with `shutil` that I am facing is that while copying the files, I need to name the file. I have written a demo version of what I am trying to do, but dont know how to scale it when I will be reading the paths of the `'.wav'` files from the txt file and copy them to my desired location using a loop.

My code for copying a single file goes as follows,

```
import shutil
original = r'/home/user/test_audio_folder_1/audio1.wav'
target=r'/home/user/final_audio_folder_1/final_audio1.wav'
shutil.copyfile(original,target)
```

Any suggestions will be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: use context manager to copy from one location to another and then delete orignal one if sucessfull. not direct move

Comment: @sahasrara62 can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import shutil

i=0
with open(r'C:/Users/turing/Desktop/location.txt', "r") as infile:
    for t in infile:
        i+=1
        x="audio"+str(i)+".wav"
        t=t.rstrip('\n')
        original= r'{}'.format(t)
        target=r'C:/Users/turing/Desktop/audio_in/' + x
        shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the built-in string's split() method within a for loop on the location.txt contents & split the name of the directory on the '/' character, then the last element in a new list would be your filename.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).